# Django Rest Framework url dispatcher

Tags: python, django, url

I am trying to interact with the SWAPI API.

I want a view that fetches all the movies(`films/`) and one that fetches one (`film/id`).

When I hit `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/films/?id=4` it enters the `get_films` function.

I am using Django==1.11 and Django Rest Framework==3.9.0 .

**my urs.py:**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'films/',views.get_films,name="get-films"),
    url(r'films/(?P<id>[0-9])/',views.get_film,name="get-film"),
]
```

**my views.py:**

```
MAX_RETRIES = 5 
API_URL= "https://swapi.co/api/" 

@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def get_films(request):
    request_url = API_URL + "films"
    print(request_url)
    if request.method == "GET":
        attempt_num = 0  # keep track of how many times we've retried
        while attempt_num < MAX_RETRIES:
            r = requests.get(request_url, timeout=10)
            if r.status_code == 200:
                data = r.json()
                return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
            else:
                attempt_num += 1
                # You can probably use a logger to log the error here
                time.sleep(5)  # Wait for 5 seconds before re-trying
        return Response({"error": "Request failed"}, status=r.status_code)
    else:
        return Response({"error": "Method not allowed"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def get_film(self, request):
    print('entered')
    request_url = API_URL + "films/" + request.query_params.get('id')
    if request.method == "GET":
        attempt_num = 0  # keep track of how many times we've retried
        while attempt_num < MAX_RETRIES:
            r = requests.get(request_url, timeout=10)
            if r.status_code == 200:
                data = r.json()
                return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
            else:
                attempt_num += 1
                # You can probably use a logger to log the error here
                time.sleep(5)  # Wait for 5 seconds before re-trying
        return Response({"error": "Request failed"}, status=r.status_code)
    else:
        return Response({"error": "Method not allowed"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 things wrong with your implementation. First, `get_film`. the arguments are wrong in this method. you need to define it like this:

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def get_film(request, id):  # <-- First argument is request which is for `HttpRequest` object. Second is `id` which is for mapping it with the url's id. 
    print('entered')
    request_url = API_URL + "films/" + str(id) 
    # rest of the code
```

Second, when calling this **api**, you need to do it like this: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/films/4/`

Answer (score 0):

The order in `urlpatterns` matter. Try changing the order of your urls. It probably matches the first one and doesn't reach the second one.

Comment: I did what you proposed,  still it enters the get_films function

Comment: Oh. `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/films/?id=4` should be `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/films/4`.

The id=4 you had was a url paramater that you would get in get_films request.GET