# How to do dynamic dispatch in Django REST Framework without an extra request?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, dynamic-dispatch

I've got a bunch of existing API endpoints with different URLs and parameters. I'd like to enable asynchronous execution of some of them by adding a general-purpose `/tasks(?P<path>.+)` endpoint which calls the `path` endpoint asynchronously, returning a Celery task ID for the client to check the status of the task at their leisure. So far it's very similar to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53696141/96588), but I was hoping there would be an existing pattern to resolve and call the relevant view **without sending another HTTP request.** Even though it would be fast enough to send a request, it would be seemingly unnecessary complexity.

It seems this might be possible at the view level, basically stripping off the URL prefix and then using the built-in URL resolver to figure out what to call asynchronously with a slightly modified request object.

Comment: It depends on what your endpoints do and how your code is organized. Sometimes I've created a /async endpoint for some specific existing sync. ones that spawn a celery task and responde right away

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly the sort of thing I'm working on. How did you do it though?

Answer (score 0):

This is just an example, the implementation depends on how your code is organized.

Assume you have the following `ViewSet`, mapped to the url '/example':

```
class ExampleViewSet(ViewSet):
    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        result = some_task()
        return Response(result)
```

Now you can create a second `ViewSet` and map it to `example/async`, or `tasks/example`:

```
class ExampleAsyncViewSet(ViewSet):
    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        result = some_task.delay()
        return Response({"task_id": result.id})
```

You could also use an argument or a query param:

```
class ExampleViewSet(ViewSet):
    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if (kwargs.get("async") is True:  # or request.query_params.get("async") ...
            result = some_task.delay()
            return Response({"task_id": result.id})
        result = some_task()
        return Response(result)
```